# can't simplify to the right form of a expression

Tags: linear-algebra

$$f(x) = x\ln x$$
$$f'(x) = \ln x+1$$

I need c from the relation:
$$f'(c) = f(n+1) - f(n)$$

$c$ should look like this

$$c = \frac{n+1}{e}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

I don't find any way to get that form

Comment: Hmm... F'(x)= 1+ln(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\ln c+1=(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln n =\\n(\ln (n+1)-\ln n)+\ln (n+1)=\\n\ln \frac{(n+1)}{n}+\ln(n+1)=\\\ \ln \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} (n+1)$$
Thus
$$\ln c+1=\ln c+\ln e=\\\ln ec=\ln \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}(n+1)=\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n(n+1)$$
It follows that 
$$c = \frac{n+1}{e}\Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n$$